# CSV - remove rows in which any column is empty

Tags: unix, csv, text

I'm playing with the Titanic data set from Kaggle. I'd like to remove any rows from train.csv that have an empty column (I know this isn't the best way to deal with missing data, but this question is interesting to me regardless).

I'd like to do this Unix-type way (using something like awk, sed, or grep), because I'm trying to get better at those tools, but I'm not even sure where to start.

Example of the data:

```
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
```

In the second row, cabin is empty, so I want to remove it from the file.

Note that the fourth column sometimes contains commas, but the column is always contained in double quotes.

ASIDE:

I'd also like to know how to do this for only specific columns, but I can ask that as a separate question if the answer to this question doesn't help me answer that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would stick to a language that has a [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) parser because those commas inside double quotes can be problematic. And it will be easier to extend to compare specific columns. Here a [python](/questions/tagged/python) example. It extracts the number of fields from header and compare that number for each line to decide if it will print or not:

```
import sys 
import csv 

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    csvwriter = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
    row = next(csvreader)
    fields = len(row)
    csvwriter.writerow(row)
    for row in csvreader:
        l = len(list(filter(str.strip, row)))
        if l < fields: continue
        csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

Assuming the code inside a file with name `script.py`, run it like:

```
python script.py infile
```

That yields:

```
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
```

Comment: I get the error "TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function". I think this might be because I have python 2.7, and according to http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/newline-conversion-in-python-3/ this is a python 3 feature.

Comment: It works if I remove the third argument. Checking the results of this visually against filtering the data in Excel, it looks like it works. Thank you for suggesting that a language with a csv parser would be a way to go. I'll accept this one.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an attempt using `sed`

```
sed -r '/(^|,)\s*(,|$)/d' file
```

This will delete all lines containing `,,`, ending with `,` and starting with `,`

`\s*` will also allow deleting rows containing any cell filled only with spaces.

**For particular Column**

You may try `awk`.

```
awk -F',' '$n{print $0}' file
```

In `$n`, replace `n` with desired column number.

Comment: The `sed` command fails if the string `,,` exists inside the field surrounded with double quotes. Not probably but possible. Similar issue for the `awk` one.

Answer (score 2):

How about excluding lines that contain `,,` or ending with `,` or starting with `,`

```
cat data.txt | sed -e '/,,/d' -e '/^,/d' -e '/,$/d'
```

It's not perfect, because quoted text may contain `,,`, which does not mean an empty column. But maybe this is good enough? You be the judge!